# Grails params encoding

Tags: tomcat, grails, encoding, nginx

I have 1 problem with params encoding, when i try request (method get) with param like q

example:

```
q=%31%1223%123%
```

when i render it a get:

```
�V�▒č
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: Is your example exactly what is sent? `%31%1223%123%` almost looks like an url-encoded string, but is invalid.

Comment: Torrent client announce request

Comment: What character encoding is being used to decode the query string? What character encoding is being used to encode the characters that you have posted above (which look like a question-mark-ina-diamnod, a capital "V", another question-mark thing, a rectangle of static, then the letter "č" to me)?

Answer (score 0):

I just spent all day fighting with this.

If you change your UrlMappings and put the param as part of the path instead of part of the querystring it will get decoded correctly.

No idea why, but thats how I fixed it.

Comment: To do this - you make change Grails Params url encoding & servlet container or app server param encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1